# Why - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section not called

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [view vChangeBackgroundToCyan];
}
```

after

```
[self.delegateForTableController.tvDelegated insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:ip.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

And how to call them?

Comment: Have you adhered to UITableView delegate?

Comment: that delegate looks ok .. can you show us the method tableView:viewForSection: please

Answer (score 8):

The class returned by tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: needs to be a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView for the tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection: method to get called.

If the returned view is of some other type, the tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection: method will not get called.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `- tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` is being called only if you provide your own view in `– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

I also hope your delegate reference is not `nil`.

Comment: As of iOS9 `tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` is called regardless of `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` being implemented